# Multiple gl.drawElements calls don't work correctly

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have the following function for drawing a scene with a Mini Cooper that uses a for loop to render each part of the car separately.

```
function drawScene() {
    var colormap = new Object();
    colormap["Body"] = [0.05, 0.05, 0.54];
    colormap["Body Chrome"] = [0.95, 0.96, 0.93];
    colormap["Roof"]=[0.85, 0.85, 0.85];
    colormap["Headlights"]=[0.95, 0.96, 0.93];
    colormap["Mirrors"]=[0.85, 0.85, 0.85];
    colormap["Brakelights"]=[0.54, 0.22, 0.22];
    colormap["Undercarriage"]=[0.2, 0.2, 0.2];
    colormap["Antenna"]=[0.2, 0.2, 0.2];
    colormap["Driver Blinker"]=[0.9, 0.5, 0.1];
    colormap["Passenger Blinker"]=[0.9, 0.5, 0.1];
    colormap["Exhaust"]=[0.95, 0.96, 0.93];
    colormap["Upper Driver Wiper"]=[0.2, 0.2, 0.2];
    colormap["Upper Passenger Wiper"]=[0.2, 0.2, 0.2];
    colormap["Lower Driver Wiper"]=[0.2, 0.2, 0.2];
    colormap["Lower Passenger Wiper"]=[0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
    colormap["Rear Wiper"]=[0.2, 0.2, 0.2];
    colormap["Vents"]=[0.1, 0.1, 0.1];
    colormap["License"]=[0.94, 0.64, 0.19];
    colormap["Front Driver Rim"]=[0.75, 0.75, 0.75];
    colormap["Front Passenger Rim"]=[0.75, 0.75, 0.75];
    colormap["Rear Driver Rim"]=[0.75, 0.75, 0.75];
    colormap["Rear Passenger Rim"]=[0.75, 0.75, 0.75];
    colormap["Front Driver Tire"]=[0.1, 0.1, 0.1];
    colormap["Front Passenger Tire"]=[0.1, 0.1, 0.1];
    colormap["Rear Driver Tire"]=[0.1, 0.1, 0.1];
    colormap["Rear Passenger Tire"]=[0.1, 0.1, 0.1];
    colormap["Brakes"]=[0.75, 0.75, 0.75];
    colormap["Rear View Mirror"]=[0.8, 0.8, 0.8];
    colormap["Interior"]=[0.4, 0.4, 0.0];
    colormap["Driver"]=[0.9, 0.9, 0.9];
    colormap["Chair"]=[0.55, 0.27, 0.075];
    colormap["Windows"]=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5];
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);



    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, miniVertexBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 4*8, 0);
    setMatrixUniforms();

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, miniIndexBuffer);
    console.log(miniCoop);
    for(part in miniCoop.parts){
        var start = miniCoop.group[miniCoop.parts[part]][0];
        var end = miniCoop.group[miniCoop.parts[part]][1];
        gl.uniform3f(shaderProgram.colour, colormap[miniCoop.parts[part]][0], colormap[miniCoop.parts[part]][1], colormap[miniCoop.parts[part]][2]);
        var offset = 2*3 * start;
        var count = 3 *(end - start);
        gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, count, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, offset);
    }
}
```

The scene however, won't draw over things in the background when drawElements() is called, resulting in the first thing being drawn, the body, to always be in the foreground, regardless of it's position in the scene, and the rest of the parts of the scene show up in the order shown in the colormap. I don't know what the problem is, and would really appreciate some help.

Example output image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNAJz.jpg
On Dropbox: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80759516/test.html

Answer (score 0):

Turn on depth testing?

```
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
```

Comment: If you look at the full thing on dropbox, I have it enabled in the webGLStart() function, which is why it's so perplexing.